# Coalesce equivalent for NULL or zero amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the easiest way to select `amountB` for both test cases where `amountA` is null or 0?

```
DECLARE @amountA float;
DECLARE @amountB float = 3.33;
select coalesce(@amountA, @amountB)

SET @amountA  = 0.00;
select coalesce(@amountA, @amountB)
```

Comment: Adding `NULLIF()`? `CASE` expression? `IIF()` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case I would use `CASE`:

```
select case when @amountA is null or @amountA = 0 then @amountB else @amountA end
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you just looking for

```
DECLARE @amountA float;
DECLARE @amountB float = 3.33;
select coalesce(nullif(@amountA, 0), @amountB);

SET @amountA  = 0.00;
select coalesce(nullif(@amountA, 0), @amountB);
```

Or using a `CASE` expression or `IIF()` function as I say in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would invert the conditions in the `CASE` in the accepted answer and use `IIF`

```
SELECT IIF(@amountA <> 0, @amountA, @amountB)
```

If @amountA is `0` or `NULL` the expression will evaluate to `false` or `unknown` respectively and both of those fall through to the `ELSE` branch.

Answer (score 2):

You could nest `case` inside the `coalesce`.

```
select coalesce(case when @amountA > 0 then @amountA end, @amountB)
```

Could also rewrite as

```
select case when @amountA > 0 then @amountA else @amountB end
```

*Note that unless you change the conditional operator above from > to <>, negative values will get assigned @amountB*

Comment: If `@amountA` is negative your code returns `@amountB` instead of `@amountA`. The  OP didn't mention any special handling for negative values.